# Can't install PostGIS extension to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, installation, postgresql-10

I just installed a fresh new install of PostgreSQL-10.5-1-win64-bigsql

Once installed I wanted to add the PostGIS extension ran: `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
Got error message could not find `C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\share\postgresql\extension\postgis.control`

I found the file at this location `C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\share\extension\`

So I thought I could just copy the postgis.control into the directory where it was being looked for and ran the create extension and got this: `ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "2.4.4"`

Comment: TMC if this issue is solved, please click on the tick to mark the right answer as the "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing PostGres Database, the installer would install Stack Builder which is used to add extensions. Is is easier to use this method. Search for Stack Builder in Windows, run it and just add PostGIS from there.

Comment: I installed 'PostgreSQL-10.5-1-win64-bigsql' It did not install the Stack Builder.  I did install other PostGres versions before trying 10 that did install the stack builder but the PostGis still had the error.  I searched for the download of stack builder on its own but found no link yet.  Maybe soluton is to use earlier version of PostGres. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the PostGres Web site, got directed to 
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Rebuilt the download, which turned out to be a much larger download file, installed and all items installed correctly now and PostGIS extension installed.
Lyes, thanks for the help, it made me do another download to make sure the stack builder installed,  Thanks.